# Pidion Bip-1300 corrupted files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, pocketpc

I'm running my application on the pocket pc, connected to the database and make a data migration. During this process my application freez. I look up, control the "ProgramStore" and it's full, but with currupted files like in the picture below, created only in the folder where is my application. And I can't delete those files that are in the programstore.

[image]

After that my application doesn't work anymore because there is no space in programstore. I tried the hard Reset option but it dosen't work. Some can help?

Comment: That looks like a dead SD card. Similar thing happened years ago on my Samsung Omnia.

Comment: but i have on this device the eprom memory

Comment: When our devices act up, I let them sit for a couple of days with no battery in it, then give it the Hard Reset.